# Write a simulation of a funny game with a dice in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a code that simulates the following game:

Roll two dice and let x be the sum of them. If x=7 or x=11 then you win. **Otherwise roll both dice again until you get x** (in which case you win) or 7 or 11 (in which case you loose).

Imagine you have a two dice, then if in the first roll you get as the sum of both 7 or 11, you win, if not, then the sum could be other number, let's say 9, then you have to continue rollin both dice until you get again 9, if in that process you get 7 or 11 agiain you loose :)

Then I wrote the following code:

```
    d1=floor(6*rand)+1;
    d2=floor(6*rand)+1;
    x=d1+d2;

    while x~=7 & x~=11
    d1=floor(6*rand)+1;
        d2=floor(6*rand)+1;
        x=d1+d2;
        if x==x
            disp('You win')
        elseif x==7 | x==11
            disp('You loose')
        end
    end
```

But it displays indefinitely the sentence "you win" and can't stop it, I know that this is because the condition "x==x" always evaluates true, but how can I fix that to have the simulation?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Among other issues, you need to re-roll the dice in each loop iteration.

Comment: Right but I don't know how to do that :), and what other issues?

Comment: I have edited my post :) what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to do re-rolls until you win? In that case you want to do the re-roll in your while-loop. Checking the same number over and over again is not going to be useful.

```
x=0;
wins=[7 11];
while min(x~=wins)
    d1=floor(6*rand)+1;
    d2=floor(6*rand)+1;
    x=d1+d2
    if max(x==wins)
        disp('You win')
    else
        disp('You loose')
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  but the thing is that you win if in the first time you roll the dice the sum is 7 or 11, if not then you roll it again until you finally pick the first sum, if you get in the process a 7 or 11 again you loose :)

Comment: @Adriaan Matlab's `min` and `max` are compatible with boolean classes. They can be used as `AND` and `OR` gates.

Comment: @Adriaan Also, Matlab is able to treat doubles as booleans. 0 = false, everything else = true. Plus, it is possible to do scalar multiplications and comparisons on matrices of any size.

Comment: Thanks, I've run your code but I think that the condition of returning to the value of the sum is missing

Comment: Is because in the game it says that when you roll both dice and you don't get a 7 or 11 we have to run it until we get the number of the first sum again ;)

Comment: JJM, I tested and found out. I didn't know you could check 1 scalar against existence in a full array. Neat.

Answer (score 1):

```
d1=floor(6*rand)+1;
d2=floor(6*rand)+1;
x=d1+d2;

kk=1;
while x~=7 && x~=11
    d1=floor(6*rand)+1;
    d2=floor(6*rand)+1;
    if kk ==1
        tmp = d1+d2;
    end
    x=d1+d2;
    if x==7 || x==11 && kk == 1
        disp('You win')
    elseif x==7 || x==11 && kk > 1
        disp('You loose')
    elseif x==tmp && kk>1
        disp('You win')
    else
        disp('You loose')  
    end
    kk = kk+1;
end
```

What is happening is that I introduced `kk`, which can be considered and iteration counter. Add that as an extra condition upon the winning condition. `if` statements then contain all the conditions you set, note that if `kk==1` I save the sum in `tmp`, against which I check the second win condition.

Test run:

```
You loose
You loose
You loose
You win
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Adriaann but the thing is that you win if in the first time you roll the dice the sum is 7 or 11, if not then you roll it again until you finally pick the first sum, if you get in the process a 7 or 11 again you loose :)

Comment: I don't get it. I can implement the 7/11 part, but Ive got no idea what you mean by *until you finally pick the first sum*

Comment: Imagine you have a two dice, then if in the first roll you get as the sum of both 7 or 11, you win, if not, then the sum could be other number, let's say 9, then you have to continue rollin both dice until you get again 9, if in that process you get 7 or 11 agiain you loose :)

Comment: Adriaan I am sorry for the question but when I am trying to run your code, MATLAB tells me that I haven't define tmp :)

Comment: Found out the same; initialise `kk=1` (What happened was that it had `kk=0` which isnt properly defined)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
x=0;

while x~=7 | x~=11
    d1=floor(6*rand)+1;
    d2=floor(6*rand)+1;
    x=d1+d2;
    if x==7 | x==11
        disp(x)
        disp('You win')
        break
    else
        disp(x)
        disp('You loose')
        a = input('You want roll again (y/n)? ','s')
        if strcmpi(a,'y')
        else
          break
       end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rafael, but what is strcmpi?

Comment: Take a Look here:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi.html

strcmpi compare two strings, so we compare if the the user wants to play again by inputting the char "y", if he dont want to, we break the while loop.

Comment: Sure, I've not tested. Let me know :)

Comment: I made a little modification, just to print the x value.

Comment: Thanks, I've run your code but I think that the condition of returning to the value of the sum is missing

Comment: Is because in the game it says that when you roll both dice and you don't get a 7 or 11 we have to run it until we get the number of the first sum again ;)

Answer (score 1):

Because you change the rule after the first round, you specify the rule of the first round with an `if` statement and the rest of the game in the `else` statement. Moreover, you need to specify the value `X` in your code. Here I use 5 as an example. If there is no result after the first round, you role the dice again with the code `d1=floor(6*rand)+1; d2=floor(6*rand)+1; x=d1+d2;`, then determine whether you win or lose. If there is still no result, you will use a while loop to keep this going until there is a win or lose situation.

```
d1=floor(6*rand)+1;
d2=floor(6*rand)+1;
x=d1+d2;
first_sum = x    % use another variable first_sum to hold the status of first roll

if x==7 || x==11
    disp('You win')
else
    d1=floor(6*rand)+1;
    d2=floor(6*rand)+1;
    x=d1+d2;
    if x== 7 || x==11
        disp('You lose')
    elseif x == first_sum
        disp('You win')
    else
        while x ~= first_sum && x~=11 && x~=7
            d1=floor(6*rand)+1;
            d2=floor(6*rand)+1;
            x=d1+d2;
            if x== 7 || x==11
                disp('You lose')
            elseif x == first_sum
                disp('You win')
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Or you can write this in a more succinct way. Since the else statement contains a structure like a `do while` loop(meaning do at least once and keep doing it if a certain condition is met), you can also code it like this :

```
d1=floor(6*rand)+1;
d2=floor(6*rand)+1;
x=d1+d2;
first_sum = x

if x==7 || x==11
    disp('You win')
else
    flag = true
    while flag    % The while loop will keep going until flag is set to false.
        d1=floor(6*rand)+1;
        d2=floor(6*rand)+1;
        x=d1+d2;
        if x== 7 || x==11
            disp('You lose')
            flag = false   % If a result is reached, stop the while loop
        elseif x == first_sum
            disp('You win')
            flag = false
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Let me run it and and if I have a doubt can I tell you?

Comment: Sure. Let me know if there is anything unclear to you.

Comment: Thanks, I've run your code but I think that the condition of returning to the value of the sum is missing

Comment: What do you mean by returning to the value of the sum? What sum?

Comment: oh is because in the game it says that when you roll both dice and you don't get a 7 or 11 we have to run it until we get the number of the first sum again ;)

Comment: But what happen if the sum is not 5, well that is the tricky step for me, how to tell MATLAB to roll the dice until you get the very first sum you've got in the very first roll :) I have edited my post, well if you want to see the example I gave :)

Comment: Ok. Now I see what you mean. So you need to use another variable, `first_sum` in my updated code, to hold the value of the first roll because your `x` could change.

Answer (score 1):

added more of a game vibe to it, also added comments so you understand what I am doing

```
win1 = 7; %these values give you a win
win2 = 11;
lose1 = 0; %can't lose on first roll. this will be set later
lose2 = 0;

streak = 0;

%while game is still going on..
while true
    newgame = input('Would you like to start a new game? Type YES or NO  --> ','s'); %user inputs string
    if strcmpi(newgame,'YES') %did user type YES?
        game = true;  % set games state to true to begin the game loop
        firstroll=true; %first roll coming up
    elseif strcmpi(newgame,'NO')
        break; % end program by exiting outer loop
    else %user didn't enter correctly so re-ask
        continue;
    end

    while game
        input('Press enter to roll dice'); %roll the dice
        d1 = floor(6*rand)+1;
        d2 = floor(6*rand)+1;

        disp('You rolled:'); %display the dice
        disp(d1);
        disp(d2);
        x=d1+d2;

        if x==win1 || x==win2  % check for a win
            streak=streak+1; %%add a win to your total
            disp('WINNER!')
        elseif x==lose1 || x==lose2
            disp('YOU LOST!')
            disp('streak:') %show how many games you won
            disp(streak)
            game = false; % end game state because you lost

            %reset winning and losing numbers
            win1=7;
            win2=11;
            lose1=0;
            lose2=0;
            streak = 0; %reset streak
        elseif firstroll   %ok, didn't win on the FIRST ROLL so lets set the NEW winning value and reroll
            win1 = x;  % we win if we roll the same value again
            win2 = x;
            lose1 = 7; % we lose if we roll a 7 or 11
            lose2 = 11;
            firstroll = false; % set firstroll false so it doesn't keep resetting the winning and losing values
            continue;
        end
    end
end
disp('Thanks for playing!')
```

Comment: Let me check it and if I got doubts can I tell you ?